# Recycle view keep loading deleted items

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have the codes below to load and filter the data from Firebase Firestore to a recycle view that Loads all the Filtered data, everything is working fine , but , when I go delete the selected item from the searched list, it does delete from the Firestore data on the web but still loaded by the Search recycle view after been deleted , looks like the Adatper still have the Data and didn't remove it after been deleted , please take a look to the codes Below in both deletenote() and getnotes() methods :-

```java
package com.example.boc.main;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;
import com.example.boc.PhoneNumbers.NoteRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.example.boc.PhoneNumbers.ViewNoteDialog;
import com.example.boc.models.Search;
import com.example.boc.search.SearchRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.example.boc.R;
import com.example.boc.Interface.IMainActivity;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.boc.models.Note;

/**
 * Created by User on 5/14/2018.
 */

public class Search_test extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        IMainActivity,
        SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    //widgets
    private FloatingActionButton mFab, mFab2;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    public FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //vars
    private View mParentLayout;
    private ArrayList<Search> mSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Note> mNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.collection("notes").document();
    private CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db.collection("notes");
    private NoteRecyclerViewAdapter mNoteRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private SearchRecyclerViewAdapter mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private DocumentSnapshot mLastQueriedDocument;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_recycler);
        mParentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_search);
        EditText userinput = findViewById(R.id.userInputtxt);


        initRecyclerView();
        getNotes();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Animatoo.animateFade(Search_test.this); //fire the slide left animation
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreatOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteNote(final Note note) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference noteRef = db
                .collection("notes").document(note.getNote_id());

        noteRef.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Deleted note");

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);// trying to make the recycle view remove the adapter but still loading the old list //


                } else {
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Failed. Check log.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
    }

    private void getNotes() {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final EditText userinput = findViewById(R.id.userInputtxt);

        CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db
                .collection("notes");

        Query notesQuery = null;
        if (mLastQueriedDocument != null) {

            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        } else {
            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        }

        notesQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String data = "";

                    for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Note note = document.toObject(Note.class);

                        mNotes.add(note);

                        if (userinput == null) {
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);

                        }

                        if (userinput != null) {

                            userinput.addTextChangedListener(
                                    new TextWatcher() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                                            final String userinputString = userinput.getText().toString();
                                            mSearch.clear();

                                            for (Note note : mNotes) {
                                                if (note.getTitle().contains(userinputString)) {

                                                    if (note != null) {

                                                        mSearch.add(note);

                                                        mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter = new SearchRecyclerViewAdapter(Search_test.this, mSearch);
                                                        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Search_test.this));
                                                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter);
                                                        mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                    }


                                                }


                                            }


                                        }


                                    }

                            );


                        }


                    }


                    if (task.getResult().size() != 0) {
                        mLastQueriedDocument = task.getResult().getDocuments()
                                .get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                    }
                    mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Query Failed. Check Logs.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        if (mNoteRecyclerViewAdapter == null) {
            mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter = new SearchRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mSearch);
        }
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateNote(final Note note) {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference noteRef = db
                .collection("notes")
                .document(note.getNote_id());

        noteRef.update(
                "title", note.getTitle(),
                "content", note.getContent(), "pos", note.getpos()
        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    makeSnackBarMessage(" تم تحديث المعلومات");
                } else {
                    makeSnackBarMessage("حدث خطأ , يرجى اعادة المحاولة");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteSelected(Note note) {
        ViewNoteDialog dialog = ViewNoteDialog.newInstance(note);
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_view_note));
    }

    @Override
    public void createNewNote(String title, String content, String pos) {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DocumentReference newNoteRef = db
                .collection("notes")
                .document();

        Note note = new Note();
        note.setTitle(title);
        note.setContent(content);
        note.setPos(pos);
        note.setNote_id(newNoteRef.getId());
        note.setUser_id(userId);

        newNoteRef.set(note).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    makeSnackBarMessage("تمت اضافة رقم الهاتف للسجل");
                    getNotes();
                } else {
                    makeSnackBarMessage(" يوجد خطأ , يرجى اعادة المحاولة");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeSnackBarMessage(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(mParentLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE :- I added this codes to the operation deletenote() and noticed that the data removed :-                                                                                                                                                          Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);    , but the screen flashes due to refreshing the activity which i dont like

Answer (score 1):

From what i can tell you never removed the element from the list(mNotes or mSearch  i think) that the adapter uses it as data source. 
So even if it's deleted from Firebase it's still in your list.

Comment: suspecting same , but need a solution for that .

Answer (score 1):

To update the list either you have to delete the note from mNotes with the position of the note selected followed by calling adapter notifyDatasetChanged().
 Or you have to load the list again from DB calling  getNotes().

Comment: deleting the note is already done and you can find the firebase Firestore removed the one that had been deleted , and note must reload the new data or remove the entry also at least , and re loading the data from firestore every time you delete somthing make it increase bandwidth usage and will cost you more money .

Comment: I agree that loading from db again is inefficient, but I saw in your code you are calling getNotes() in create new note function. You can try deleting the item from both list with  arrayList.remove(position of deleted note) followed by calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER 1
I got it, thanks for you all for your time, the solution was by clearing both array lists that is loaded with old data and filtered data, then notify the adapter, after that recall the get notes() method to reload the new data from the firebase firestore which does not contain the deleted ones anymore :-

```js
    @Override
    public void deleteNote(final Note note){
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference noteRef = db
                .collection("notes").document(note.getNote_id());

        noteRef.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Deleted fgfff");
                    mNotes.clear();
                    mSearch.clear();
                    mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getNotes();



                }
                else{
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Failed. Check log.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You don't even need to clear both list and load again from dB, just remove the deleted item from both the list with arraylist.remove(position), then call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: i will try it now and will replay to you

Comment: From the note selection event, like onClick

Comment: Try with ArrayList.indexOf(note)

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER 2

Iliked this one more as long as it doesnot load the data again , as getnotes() will add the data back every time the user input a char.

```js
noteRef.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Deleted fgfff");

                    mNotes.remove(note);
                    mSearch.remove(note);
                    mSearchRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }
                else{
                    makeSnackBarMessage("Failed. Check log.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```